# Invalid cross thread access in silverlight

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, drawing, line

i am making an application in silverlight 3.0. In that application i have one public method as

```
public void DrawWavform()
{
     Line[,] line = new Line[10,200];
     line[i,j]= new Line();//i am getting error here of invalid thread access
    //some operation

}
```

In application i am creating different threads as per user inputs and  calling DrawWaveform method from that newly created thread. I want to parallel opeation.Please suggest me solution.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any operation changing the GUI must be executed on the UI thread. This can be done using the [dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.dispatcher%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () =>
{
  // update ui
});
```

or

```
(SomeDependencyObject).Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () => { /* ... */ } );
```

Anyway, this code should be used very rarely and contain only UI related code. Executing expensive operations on the UI thread will cause your application to hang.